# Do most email clients support MHTML?

Tags: email, email-client, mhtml

Do all modern email clients (online and desktop apps) support [MHTML email content](http://people.dsv.su.se/~jpalme/ietf/mhtml.html) in which images and other resources are embedded in the email?

In addition is this the standard that should be used to get a consistent HTML email message out or is it better to send HTML emails with linked resources.

Note: I am aware of the [7 reasons why HTML e-mail is EVIL](http://www.georgedillon.com/web/html_email_is_evil.shtml) but it is essential in this case. Also I have seen the article on [css support in HTML emails](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and know these pitfalls.

Comment: Wow I asked this question 12 years ago, think it is safe to say things have moved on a little from then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty well all of them.  MIME multipart is pretty durn common at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just keep in mind that many clients do not load the images by default to avoid giving away "alive" account details to spammers.

Don't expect JavaScript to work (some users have it and it works), but Outlook/Outlook Express have had a bad history with JavaScript and IIRC have completely blocked it by default in recent versions.