# Inline CSS/Javascript into a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

I am looking for a simple commandline script/program to automatically "inline" all external css and javascript references for a html file. I basically want to create a single self-contained html file suitable for sending via E-Mail. An additional bonus would be if it could also inline images as data: UIRs, but that part is not so important.

Comment: +1 I am looking for that too. Very interested to see what turns up.

Comment: which Server-side script are you running on?

Comment: PHP for me. Don't know about the TO.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT : I wrote a little Python script for fun. It seems to work pretty well :**

[Inline2Mail](http://web.archive.org/web/20100214004212/http://www.e-vidence.net/?p=338)

Or you can still try with :

[Front compiler](http://github.com/MadRabbit/frontcompiler) does something like that but it implies javascript. You have an online solution as well, with [premailer](http://code.dunae.ca/premailer.web/). Finally you have a [Python](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/premailer.py) and a [Ruby](http://code.google.com/p/premailer/source/browse/trunk/bin/premailer.rb?r=87) script to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to "import" external references like <script src=""> and @import url("foo.css") into my html file to make it a single file. Both the python and ruby script appear to do something else.

Comment: Premailer does this import, whereas the python script inject the css directly in the tags. They are complementary.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Node.js library which solves exactly your problem: https://github.com/remy/inliner/ It can be used both as a commandline script and a library.

It will make you a single `.html` file which can be sent anywhere by any means and be opened later in any browser without the need in Internet connection.

If you think about inlining CSS and Javascript to make a HTML *body of an email*, just forget about it. Most Email clients out there will either ignore or badly damage your styles and I think all email clients will just plainly drop the inline Javascript in the body of emails.

Answer (score 2):

This Python project of mine can help with getting the CSS styles inline https://github.com/rennat/pynliner

Answer (score -1):

If it's not something that needs to be automated and you're using Windows you could open the web page in Internet Explorer and save it as '**Web Archive, single file (*.mht)**'. This will pack everything into a single file, including CSS, JavaScript and images. Note that the recipients needs to have access to Internet Explorer to be able to open the Web Archive. Neither Google Chrome nor Firefox supports mht files, so it's probably a Microsoft only feature.

Comment: Opera supports it too, and it's a MIME multipart format so e-mail clients should support it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793404/do-most-email-clients-support-mhtml

Comment: This is a solution, surely, but not exactly what the OP asked. `*.mht` files are special format, essentially being a archive file with all assets put into one place. The question was supposedly asked about making a HTML page which can be loaded as usual in any browser, either via HTTP request, or locally from file. This is something which `*.mht` format cannot provide, and which should be solved programmatically.